# How to create View with Full Content and Teaser

Tags: 7, views, nodes

Can I create a View of nodes which has 'Full Content' for one node and 'Teaser' for the others ?

My page consists of a node containing full content followed by summary nodes which link to their pages.

I have a workaround but it not ideal:

I selected 'Teaser' `Show:Content | Teaser` in the View for all my nodes and increased 'Summary or Trimmed length' to 60000. That way, nodes with summary will show up and nodes without summary will display 60000 chars from body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, list only the full node in a Views display, then add a second display of type "Attachment". This attachment view will then list all the teasers, and can be configured so that it always "attaches" to the bottom of the primary one.

This way you can get both Views, but they always render together.